# Two objects created in spring why?

Tags: java, spring

I am getting familiar with Spring. Strangely code below invokes constructor twice whereas I expected it to be called once. Can someone help?

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextStartedEvent;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;

public class DemoClass implements ApplicationListener<ContextStartedEvent> {

    private String message;
    private int nrOfMessages;



    public DemoClass(String mes, int nr) {
        message = mes;
        nrOfMessages = nr;
        System.out.println("Demo class constructor. Parameters: " + mes + " " + nr);
    }

    // a setter method to set List
    public void setNrOfMessages(int nr) {
        this.nrOfMessages = nr;
    }


    // Message setter
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    // prints and returns all the elements of the list.
    public void dumpContents() {
            System.out.println("Message: " + message + " Nr of messages: " + nrOfMessages);
        }

    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextStartedEvent event) {
          System.out.println("ContextStartedEvent Received");
       }


}
```

The bean and main:

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

public class MainApp {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ConfigurableApplicationContext  context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

        context.start();

        // Create an object
        DemoClass obj = (DemoClass) context.getBean("democlassBean");

        // Dump contents
        obj.dumpContents();

    }
}
```

bean

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


   <bean id="democlassBean" class="com.tutorialspoint.DemoClass"
    scope="prototype">
      <constructor-arg value="Hello world beans."/>
      <constructor-arg value="300"/>        
   </bean>

   <bean class="com.tutorialspoint.InitHelloWorld"></bean>


</beans>
```

This is the output:

```
Demo class constructor. Parameters: Hello world beans. 300
BeforeInitialization : democlassBean
AfterInitialization : democlassBean
ContextStartedEvent Received 
Demo class constructor. Parameters: Hello world beans. 300    
BeforeInitialization : democlassBean
AfterInitialization : democlassBean
Message: Hello world beans. Nr of messages: 300
```

You can see constructor is being called **twice** - why???

---

Here is also code for initHelloWorld:

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;

public class InitHelloWorld implements BeanPostProcessor {

   public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
      System.out.println("BeforeInitialization : " + beanName);
      return bean;  // you can return any other object as well
   }

   public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
      System.out.println("AfterInitialization : " + beanName);
      return bean;  // you can return any other object as well
   }

}
```

Comment: Out of morbid curiosity, what happens if you change the scope to singleton?

Comment: isnt democlassBean autowired by or created into InitHelloWorld?
It is easiest to check by debuging into constructor. In the debuger, you will see stack trace, which should give a hint why bean is constructed.

Comment: @Makoto Constructor called once. But also it is called earlier than the Contextstarted event, is that right?

Comment: So my immediate *hunch* here is that it's being invoked multiple times because it's eligible to be; if you wired that bean as a singleton I would only ever expect it to be instantiated once.

Comment: @BartoszBilicki No No, here is code for inithelloworld, http://codepad.org/OZAgT5M3, it does nothing basically, just pringint

Comment: @Makoto Yeah but come on I requested only single instance of it in main......

Comment: I think it is because DemoClass  is ApplicationListener.
first instance is created for listner sake, and another one as bean. what will happen if you remove ApplicationListener from this bean?

Comment: You're misunderstanding IoC:  Spring is managing the bean (so it can instantiate it however many times it feels it's necessary, or however it's configured).  You're asking for whatever Spring can give you for that bean.

Comment: @BartoszBilicki Yes if I remove listener part it gets called once.............so, there is no problem?

Comment: @Makoto If I remove implements listener it gets called once ....

Comment: @BartoszBilicki  you can even see first call precedes the ContextStartedEvent

Comment: Well of course because the bean first needs to be created and initialized before it can handle the event...

Answer (score 2):

It seems, it is not good idea to have prototype bean to act as ApplicationListener. 
Check http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/35965-applicationlistener-interface-makes-beans-eagerly-instantiated
for details.

You can make it work, but with some exta steps are required (described in lined post). Note that linked post is somewhat old (year 2007) and it is likely that some of the implementation details covered there are not valid anymore.

If you really care about number of instances being created- what about creating two classes- one as prototype, and another (singlelton) that acts as ApplicationListener?